# How to enter into a method during debugging (two ways) in visual studio?

Tags: c#-4.0

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DebugTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] book = {"Java","Android","C sharp","Html","CSS" };

```
        Console.Write("Book name is :");
        Console.WriteLine(book[2]);
        int[] data = { 10, 25, 35, 12, 45, 36 };

        int new_value = data[2] + data[3];

        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 25;
        float num3 = .25f;
        float add = num1 + num2 + num3;


        Console.WriteLine(new_value);
       float result= multi(25, 2.5f);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


     static public float multi(int a, float b)
    {

        return a * b;
    }


}
```

}

Comment: You don't appear to have actually asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio IDE, first you need to set your break points, locate the method which you want to enter, then when you are in debugging mode, you can press:

- F5: Go to the next break point
- F10: Go to the next line
- F11: Enter into the selected method or function